# Azure Kubernetes - Isito vs Nginx Controller?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, istio, azure-aks

I am trying to deploy an application on Azure Kubernetes and trying to understand when would I use Service mesh vs Ingress controller. As Istio service mesh is so powerful, why would anyone use Nginx Ingress controller?

Comment: Because you always want the least complexity component that does the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned service mesh (E.g.  [Ambassador](https://www.getambassador.io/learn/kubernetes-ingress/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIqtOT6Kyx6gIVhumyCh3PKAf9EAAYASAAEgK9nPD_BwE) or [Istio](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/)) is very powerful tool and has great number of advantages over simple ingress controller like [Nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/).

On the other hand there are users that prefer simplicity and lightweight solutions over complex systems. Nginx currently offers different features in their ingress depending on the type of subscription as listed [here](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/nginx-ingress-controllers.md).

Different projects have different requirements and sometimes simple nginx ingress can be more optimal choice over service mesh. This is why some people decide to use it rather than learn how to use service mesh.

Check out [this](https://medium.com/flant-com/comparing-ingress-controllers-for-kubernetes-9b397483b46b) article which compares most of the popular kubernetes ingress controllers.

[This](https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2017/05/taking-zero-downtime-load-balancing-even-further.html) article shows a great example of pushing HAproxy and Nginx combination to its limits.